# osnadmin request for orderer to join channel fails with connection refused in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have created a orderer node and a channel genesis block but when i try to join the orderer to the channel using admin client/ osnadmin. the connection results in error: connection refused.
Somehow the orderer node is not accepting the request. I am using the newer approach to create channel(no system-channel) I have linked my orderer.yaml settings and the logs of its container for reference. I'm literally stuck, can anybody help?
**Orderer settings for docker container**

```
peer0.orderer:
    container_name: peer0.orderer
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=localhost
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPMETHOD=none
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=8050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/key.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/tlscacerts/tls-localhost-7059.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ORDERER_CHANNELPARTICIPATION_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_LISTENADDRESS=localhost:8059
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
      # - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/key.pem
      # - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/cert.pem
      # - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
      # - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/tlscacerts/tls-localhost-7059.pem
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:8050
      - 8059:8059
    networks:
      - supplychain
    volumes:
      - ./organizations/peerOrganizations/orderer/peer0.orderer/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./organizations/peerOrganizations/orderer/peer0.orderer/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tl
```

**Channel Configuration:**

```
Organizations:
  ID: manufacturerMSP

    MSPDir: ./organizations/peerOrganizations/manufacturer/msp

    Policies: &manufacturer-policies
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.member')"

  - &orderer-org
    Name: orderer-org

    SkipAsForeign: false

    ID: OrdererMSP

    MSPDir: ./organizations/peerOrganizations/orderer/msp

    Policies: &orderer-policies
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.member')"

    OrdererEndpoints:
      - "127.0.0.1:8050"
Capabilities:
  Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    V2_0: true

  Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V2_0: true

  Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V2_5: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  ACLs: &ACLsDefault

    _lifecycle/CheckCommitReadiness: /Channel/Application/Writers
    _lifecycle/CommitChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Writers

    _lifecycle/QueryChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Writers

    _lifecycle/QueryChaincodeDefinitions: /Channel/Application/Writers

    lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers

    lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers

    lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers

    lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers

    qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers

    qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers

    qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers

    qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers

    qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers


    cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

    cscc/GetChannelConfig: /Channel/Application/Readers


    peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers

    peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Writers


    event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers

    event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

  Organizations:

  Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
    LifecycleEndorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Endorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

  Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: etcdraft

  Addresses:
    - 127.0.0.1:8050
  BatchTimeout: 2s
  BatchSize:
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 10 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 2 MB
  MaxChannels: 0

  EtcdRaft:
    Consenters:
      - Host: peer0.orderer
        Port: 8050
        ClientTLSCert: ./organizations/peerOrganizations/orderer/peer0.orderer/tls/cert.pem
        ServerTLSCert: ./organizations/peerOrganizations/orderer/peer0.orderer/tls/cert.pem

    Options:
      TickInterval: 500ms

      ElectionTick: 10
      HeartbeatTick: 1

      MaxInflightBlocks: 5

      SnapshotIntervalSize: 16 MB

  Organizations:
    

  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"

  Capabilities:
    <<: *OrdererCapabilities

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

  Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
Profiles:
  SampleAppChannelEtcdRaft:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      OrdererType: etcdraft
      Organizations:
        - <<: *orderer-org
          Policies:
            <<: *orderer-policies
            Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - <<: *manufacturer-org
          Policies:
            <<: *manufacturer-policies
            Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('manufacturerMSP.member')"
```

**logs produced by orderer docker container on start**

```
docker logs peer0.orderer
2023-06-26 16:12:17.251 UTC 0001 WARN [localconfig] completeInitialization -> General.GenesisFile should be replaced by General.BootstrapFile
2023-06-26 16:12:17.251 UTC 0002 INFO [localconfig] completeInitialization -> Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2023-06-26 16:12:17.252 UTC 0003 INFO [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> Orderer config values:
    General.ListenAddress = "localhost"
    General.ListenPort = 8050
    General.TLS.Enabled = true
    General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/key.pem"
    General.TLS.Certificate = "/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/cert.pem"
    General.TLS.RootCAs = [/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/tlscacerts/tls-localhost-7059.pem]
    General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    General.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
    General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
    General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.RootCAs = []
    General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
    General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
    General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 100
    General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
    General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
    General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
    General.GenesisMethod = "file"
    General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
    General.BootstrapMethod = "none"
    General.BootstrapFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
    General.Profile.Enabled = false
    General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
    General.LocalMSPDir = "/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp"
    General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
    General.BCCSP.Default = "SW"
    General.BCCSP.SW.Security = 256
    General.BCCSP.SW.Hash = "SHA2"
    General.BCCSP.SW.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
    General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
    General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
    General.MaxRecvMsgSize = 104857600
    General.MaxSendMsgSize = 104857600
    FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
    FileLedger.Prefix = ""
    Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
    Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
    Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
    Kafka.Verbose = false
    Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
    Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
    Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
    Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
    Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 3
    Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
    Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
    Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
    Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
    Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
    Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
    Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
    Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
    Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
    ChannelParticipation.Enabled = true
    ChannelParticipation.MaxRequestBodySize = 1048576
    Admin.ListenAddress = "localhost:8059"
    Admin.TLS.Enabled = false
    Admin.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Admin.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Admin.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Admin.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Admin.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Admin.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
2023-06-26 16:12:17.254 UTC 0004 INFO [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2023-06-26 16:12:17.284 UTC 0005 INFO [blkstorage] NewProvider -> Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains
2023-06-26 16:12:17.297 UTC 0006 INFO [orderer.commmon.multichannel] InitJoinBlockFileRepo -> Channel Participation API enabled, registrar initializing with file repo /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/pendingops
2023-06-26 16:12:17.316 UTC 0007 INFO [orderer.common.server] Main -> Starting without a system channel
2023-06-26 16:12:17.316 UTC 0008 INFO [orderer.common.server] Main -> Setting up cluster
2023-06-26 16:12:17.316 UTC 0009 INFO [orderer.common.server] reuseListener -> Cluster listener is not configured, defaulting to use the general listener on port 8050
2023-06-26 16:12:17.316 UTC 000a INFO [certmonitor] trackCertExpiration -> The enrollment certificate will expire on 2024-06-25 16:02:00 +0000 UTC
2023-06-26 16:12:17.316 UTC 000b INFO [certmonitor] trackCertExpiration -> The server TLS certificate will expire on 2024-06-25 16:02:00 +0000 UTC
2023-06-26 16:12:17.316 UTC 000c INFO [certmonitor] trackCertExpiration -> The client TLS certificate will expire on 2024-06-25 16:02:00 +0000 UTC
2023-06-26 16:12:17.317 UTC 000d INFO [orderer.commmon.multichannel] InitJoinBlockFileRepo -> Channel Participation API enabled, registrar initializing with file repo /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/pendingops
2023-06-26 16:12:17.321 UTC 000e INFO [orderer.commmon.multichannel] startChannels -> Registrar initializing without a system channel, number of application channels: 0, with 0 consensus.Chain(s) and 0 follower.Chain(s)
2023-06-26 16:12:17.321 UTC 000f INFO [orderer.common.server] Main -> Starting orderer:
 Version: v2.5.3
 Commit SHA: 8e3bbcc
 Go version: go1.20.5
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

I have tried changing ports for admin requests and have gone through the orderer logs but got no results. I am using the latest settings as per the documentation to create the channel without first creating system channel.